# Create posts on user registration

Tags: posts, user-registration, actions, wp-insert-post

How can I create let say 3 posts after the user finish the registration ?

The ideal outcome would be to create 3 posts using the user as the author of the posts and with some pre-defined values. (post title and slug)

The post title and slug would be created from info that the user will provide on the registration form.

An example:

User registers and provide Name, Surname, Email (all fields are mandatory)
Three posts are created and the user will be the author of each post.
Each post will have in the title and slug info from the registration form

- 1- Jon Doe Bio | jon-doe-bio
- 2- Jon Doe Portfolio | Jon-doe-portfolio
- 3- Jon Doe Contact | jon-doe-contact

*In the example above it seems unnecessary to have the ability to edit the slug but there will be posts with words like: in, is, at, and, that will be removed otherwise. Also note that the "pre-defined values would be: Bio, Portfolio and Contact.

It would be close to the "welcome" posts created by wordpress after install.

Any idea of how to ?

I know I need to use `wp_insert_post( $my_post );` and probably `add_action('user_register', 'some_function');` but I don't know how to create 3 posts in one shot using `wp_insert_post( $my_post );` and how to trigger that after the user finish the registration process.

Any idea how to accomplish this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You kind of answered the question yourself already,

Create a function that will create the 3 posts ex:

```
function create_new_user_posts($user_id){
        if (!$user_id>0)
                return;
        //here we know the user has been created so to create 
        //3 posts we call wp_insert_post 3 times.
        // Create post object
        $my_bio_post = array(
             'post_title' => 'bio',
             'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $bio = wp_insert_post( $my_bio_post );
        $my_portfolio_post = array(
             'post_title' => 'portfolio',
             'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $portfolio = wp_insert_post( $my_portfolio_post );
        $my_contact_post = array(
             'post_title' => 'bio',
             'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $contact = wp_insert_post( $my_contact_post );

        //and if you want to store the post ids in 
        //the user meta then simply use update_user_meta
        update_user_meta($user_id,'_bio_post',$bio);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'_portfolio_post',$portfolio);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'_contact_post',$contact);
}
```

and you hook that function using `user_register` hook

```
add_action('user_register','create_new_user_posts');
```

**Update**
When you hook a function to `user_register` the function receives the user id so you can use that to get whatever information you want about that user ex:

```
$user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
```

and now $user is a USER object so you can change the post title to user the user info ex:

```
'post_title' => $user->user_firstname . " ". $user->user_lastname . 'bio'
```

Comment: I was close :) but for some reason I thought It was a bit more complex. Just one thing... there is no mention to the post slug, is there any way to set the slug for post containing in, is, at, and words ?

Comment: Sorry but this does not actually uses the user info on the post title, or slug :(

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to use the user data

Comment: @Bainternet, I was trying to use use user_register hook. 
S2Member was installed there with Firstname, Lastname field enabled.
So while user were registering, I could retrieve user fields but not user meta fields like firstname/lastname etc.

I've also tried with get_user_meta, but no luck.

But those fields were updated in profile fields.

Any suggestion?

Comment: try setting your hook proiorty to a higher value ex: `add_action('user_register','you_callback_function',999);`